# How do i change the x and y axis on my bar graph/chart python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

So i can't for the life of me figure out how to get my graph to look like the following

[image]

currently my graph looks like this

[image]

and i want it to show the possible dice outcomes so 1-6 on the x axis and then how many times each one was rolled on the y axis. Here is my code if anyone want to help

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("how many times do you want to roll the dice?")
y = input()
x = int(y)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,7, size=(x, 1)))
df.index += 1

heads = ["Roll number", "Dice number"]

print(tabulate(df, headers = heads, tablefmt="fancy_grid",))

bg = df.plot.bar(x = None,y = None, fontsize='9',stacked=True, title='Dice')

plt.show()
```

Comment: pass `x='Dice', y='Frequence'` instead of `x=None, y=None`

Comment: You need to count the values, e.g. via `ax = df[0].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(rot=0)`. Supposing the column with the values still has its default name of `0`. `sort_index()` will sort via the index, the default would be sorted on count.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are using for the plot does not contain frequencies.
After you create the dataset, try the following:

```
# renaming the dataset columns
heads = ["Roll number", "Dice number"]
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = heads

# using GROUPBY to calculate the frequencies
freq = df.groupby('Dice number')['Roll number'].count().reset_index()

# plotting the results example 1
bg = freq.plot.bar(x = 'Dice number',y = 'Roll number', fontsize='9', title='Frequency vs Die Number')
plt.xlabel('Die Number')
plt.ylabel('Frequency');

# plotting the results example 2
plt.bar(x = 'Dice number', height='Roll number', data=freq)
plt.xlabel('Die Number')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Frequency vs Die Number');
```